# Lua UDP Socket sendto only on loopback interface?

Tags: sockets, lua, udp

```
local udp = socket.udp()
udp:setoption("broadcast", true)
udp:setsockname("*",0)
udp:settimeout(2)
udp:sendto(data, "255.255.255.255", 137)
```

The above code only transmits on loopback interface, but not on en0 (verified via WireShark). I tried changing setsockname to the IP address on en0, but still no dice.

I have also tried using network-prefix.255 instead of 255.255.255.255 - does not make a difference either.

Similar code written in python on the same machine works just fine! Seems like some Lua specific thing I am not doing right

Comment: Have you tried simply removing the call to `setsockname()` altogether? Let the OS decide which interface to bind the socket to. Unless your machine has multiple networks installed, and you want to broadcast only to a specific network.

Comment: Broadcast to 255.255.255.255 was deprecated last century. Use the subnet broadcast address.

Comment: Yes, I only added setsockname because of this problem. does not work without it either, and as I mentioned in my post, I tried the subnet broadcast address too - not working. And the exact same code written in python works perfectly.